# Does anyone know of a way to acquire a REAL credit card that is specifically designated for ecommerce testing purposes?

Tags: testing, e-commerce

What I mean is we always want to test something in the actual real world live production environment, regardless of any testing we do with any fake paypal credit card numbers or other sandboxed numbers. So instead of using our personal cards, I wonder if there is a credit company that will supply a fully feature credit card specifically for the purpose of this kind of real world testing? I suppose the answer may simply be just to get yourself a credit card and only use it for that, but I'd want to be sure it was 'out of the loop' when it came to affecting credit scores or that kind of thing.

Comment: I wonder, what would you ask for if you were a surgeon...

Comment: If you find a place to supply a test credit card with a number that works, let me know. I'll use it for, uh, testing...

Comment: @Pavel well done, that made me LOL

Answer (score 12):

A prepaid debit card would serve the same purpose and wouldn't involve anyone's credit score.

I've only worked with a few gateways, mostly Authorize.net, I've never seen a real credit card number to use, just test numbers. We've just always reimbursed ourselves (and made small purchases). The prepaid debit would be even easier.

Comment: Don't you end up paying service fees to the card issuer? That could get expensive couldn't it?

Comment: @SnOrfus You pay a transaction fee and a small percentage, yeah, so it will cost money, a few percent per transaction. No way to do it for free, that I'm aware of.

Comment: Yea, get yourself some Visa gift cards and use those. There will be a few bucks of loss in the deal but if it costs $20 to make sure your product works right who cares

Answer (score 1):

If you're big enough that you're talking to VISA and friends directly, just ask them. But  most companies will use payment providers, and the ones I've worked with provided us with test environments against which we'd build our test environments.

For go-live verification, we'd use live credit cards, because we don't want any non-production stuff in production. However, this would be a card issued against the company, not tied to any person. You'd get such a credit card directly from the big issuers. They're sometimes known as a "purchasing card". These cards are specifically designed with limitations, such as a predefined list of suppliers. In this case, that list would just contain yourself.

(Quick googling: http://www.mastercard.com/us/business/en/middlemarket/mmpurchasing_issuerlist.html, http://usa.visa.com/corporate/corporate_solutions/payment/purchasing_provider.jsp )